# Custom Array Adapter Assistance

Tags: android, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

Alright, this has been driving me nuts and I'm resorting to bugging you guys for help as much as I like to figure things out on my own this has been a nightmare. I'm making an app, for learning purposes that parses the son data of the front page of reddit and populates the info into a list view. I have a few classes:

The Downloader Class

```
public class DataDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private String downloadedData;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    downloadedData = downloadData(params[0]);
    if(downloadedData == null){
        Log.d("DataDownloader", "There was an error downloading the file");
    }
    return downloadedData;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String downloadedFile) {
    super.onPostExecute(downloadedFile);
}

private String downloadData(String urlPath){

    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

    try{
        URL urlAddress = new URL(urlPath);
        HttpURLConnection connect = (HttpURLConnection) urlAddress.openConnection();
        int serverResponse = connect.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("DataDownloader", "Server responded with response code: " + serverResponse);
        InputStream stream = connect.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
        int charRead;
        char[] inputBuffer = new char[500];
        while(true){
            charRead = streamReader.read(inputBuffer);
            if(charRead <= 0){
                break;
            }
            buffer.append(String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charRead));
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.d("DataDownloader", "MalformedURLException");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("DataDownloader", "IOException");
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

The JSON parser class

```
public class JSONParser {

private String jsonData;
private ArrayList<Submission> submissions;

public JSONParser(String jsonData) {
    this.jsonData = jsonData;
    submissions = new ArrayList<Submission>();
}

public ArrayList<Submission> getSubmissions() {
    return submissions;
}

public void parseJSON() {
    Submission submissionContents = null;

    if (jsonData != null) {
        Log.d("JSONParser.parseJSON", "Looks like JSON data to me");
        try {
            JSONObject redditJSONObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            JSONObject data = redditJSONObject.getJSONObject("data");
            JSONArray children = data.getJSONArray("children");

            for(int i = 0; i < children.length(); i++){
                submissionContents = new Submission();
                JSONObject submissionDetails = children.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject submissionInfo = submissionDetails.getJSONObject("data");
                submissionContents.setTitle(submissionInfo.getString("title"));
                submissionContents.setAuthor(submissionInfo.getString("author"));
                submissionContents.setSubReddit(submissionInfo.getString("subreddit"));
                submissionContents.setThumbnailLink(submissionInfo.getString("thumbnail"));
                submissionContents.setUrlLink(submissionInfo.getString("url"));
                submissionContents.setNumComments(submissionInfo.getInt("num_comments"));
                submissionContents.setScore(submissionInfo.getInt("score"));
                submissions.add(submissionContents);
            }


        } catch (JSONException j) {
            Log.d("JSON.parseJSON", "Error creating JSON object");
        }

    } else {
        Log.d("JSONParser", "The file was empty!");
    }

}
```

}

And a class I have to download the bitmap of each link via the thumbnail url.

```
public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
    String imageUrl = params[0];
    Bitmap image = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        InputStream imageStream = url.openStream();
        image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("ImageDownloader", "Error establishing connection to url: " + imageUrl);
    }
    return image;
}

}
```

}

I can easily implement a regular ArrayAdapter to populate the list but this will only populate it with text and I'm looking for a way to populate it with an image as well. I know I have to create a custom adapter but I honestly haven't been able to figure it out. I understand you need to create an xml that is a representation of each row and I've done that. This xml includes an image and 2 text views. I have my "submissions" array that contains each submissions contents (title, date etc) as a Submission object but I also have to download the image somewhere in there. Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: its difficult to understand your problem. You mean you have the  text data and image and you are finding it difficult to display them using custom adapter right?  Or you are not able to fetch image data properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're populating images from a web url this problem has been solved for you on Android.

I highly recommend looking into either [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) from Square or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) from Google. Both have very simple syntax and will solve your issue nicely. They'll also handle caching, and handling the issue of your view scrolling off screen before loading its image and further recycling issues.

With both you'll end up with something like:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
```

While you're learning Android try replacing your ListView with a more modern [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html), it handles the recycle pattern for you and makes you cooler to boot.

Comment: Thanks, Keith! Looking into RecyclerView. I'm actually fairly new to Java as well, I've only used it for a couple of months and prior to that, I'd used Python as my first language for approx 7 months so this is still new and intimidating stuff to me. Thanks for the tip.